# How to call static function from Helper in Laravel blade file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have custom class in path:

```
app/Http/Helpers/Helper/Helper.php
```

with namespace is: `namespace App\Helpers;`

It has a static method:

```php
public static function getMonthName($monthNumber)
{
    return date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNumber, 1));
}
```

I tried to call this method from template Laravel:

```
{{ \App\Http\Helpers\Helper::getMonthName($i) }}
```

But it does not work:

```
Class 'App\Http\Helpers\Helper' not found
```

Comment: Reference the namespace `App\Helpers\Helper::getMonthName($i)` or update your namespace to `namespace App\Http\Helpers;` should do the trick

Comment: your namespace and reference diffferes!!

Comment: ``` Call to undefined method App\Helpers\Helper::getMonthName() ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update the namespace to be :

```
namespace App\Http\Helpers\Helper;
```

namespace must be the same as the class path, because laravel uses `spl_autoload` to load classes dynamically

Comment: Then in template how? `{{ Helper::getMonthName($i) }}`?

Comment: in template : {{ App\Http\Helpers\Helper\Helper::getMonthName($i) }}

Answer (score 1):

Do it like everyone else, make `helpers.php` (in root, where `.env` file is).

```
if (! function_exists('get_month_name')) {
    function get_month_name(int $month)
    {
        return date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1));
    }
}
```

and in your `composer.json` autoload it:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

now you are able to call your helper function everywhere in code base

Answer (score 1):

If someone is trying out to use helpers function in a blade make sure you do the following things.

```
//composer.json

"files":[
        "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
 ],


//app.php

'aliases'=> [
 ...
 'Helper'=> 'App\Helpers\Helper::class',
 ]
```

and in your blade you could use if `Helper.php` are static functions

```
{{ Helper::getStatusColor($item->status) }}
```

Comment: `'App\Helpers\Helper::class',` probably this doesn't need quotation.

Answer (score 0):

Best to add it to your **config/app.php**.

```
'aliases' => [
    'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class,
]
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in [Abhi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65964792/2227743). When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.